# EF6 Help in defining the foreign key of my model (optional foreign key & conflicting multiplicities)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent

I am new to EF6 and fluent API, but I really tried all the possibilities before trying to bother you here but I am kind of stuck now.

I have the following model:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String City { get; set; }

}
```

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. The event should have a required field `Address`
2. The address can be used in an event or in another class (let's call it `Person` for example). Therefore, it shouldn't be directly be bound to the `Event` class
3. When deleting an `Event` (or `Person`), I want to cascade and delete the linked `Address`

I tried many possibilities in Fluent API by looking at the documentations and searching on the net. Despite that, I kept having various issues: conflicting multiplicities, inconsistent model or not being able to cascade on delete.

Could someone please help? I am really stuck! :)

Thank you!

!!!UPDATE!!!
As requested, here's the best solution I could find:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Address.Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String City { get; set; }
}
```

And the fluent code as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Address)
            .WithOptional()
            .Map(e => e.MapKey("AddressId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This implementation adds a foreign key in the Event table to the Address table. However, the cascade on delete will work in the following direction: deleting the Address will delete the Event. Unfortunately, I am trying to accomplish the opposite: I want the Address to be deleted only when the Event is!

Thank you again :)

Comment: Please show the best mapping alternative you found so we can proceed on that and find something that's more likely to be what you want.

Comment: _The address can be used in an event or in another class_ Do you mean the _same_ address, or `Address` in general can be related to anything? You mapped 1:1, so one address can only belong to one entity at a time.

Comment: I meant the Address class not instance. One record of Address can be user either with an Event record, or with a Person record, but not both at the same time. I am sorry I haven't mentioned that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are fighting each other.

- Cascade delete is from principal to dependent, so when an `Address` should be deleted when an `Event` is, the `Event` must be the principal (the entity *to* which a foreign refers).
- If more than one class must have an `Address`, the other classes should refer to `Address`, which makes `Address` the principal.

There is an alternative. `Address` could have two foreign keys, to `Person` and to `Event`. But this is not very appealing, because the keys must both be nullable and there is no database constraint to enforce that they are mutually exclusive.

Another alternative is to make `Address` a complex type, so both the `Event` and the `Person` tables will have all address columns. Of course this is not well normalized, and you can't handle `Addresses` as separate entities, but at least there is no cascade issue, because an address is part of the `Event` record.

I think your best option is to have several classes refer to `Address` and write logic to delete orphan addresses.

Comment: Hello Gert, I was kind of thinking about what you just mentioned and I think I will opt out for that solution. Thank you very much for confirming that though :)